# Div height is not adjusting when RadMultiPage loads a long page

Tags: asp.net, css, telerik

My asp.net page has a div (#multipage) that contains a Telerik MultiPage control.  For those who are not familiar with Telerik controls think of it as a iFrame that loads various other page in response to the user's clicks on a tab control.  My problem is that one of my pages loaded by the multipage control is a long one.  And when it loads the browser wraps it with scrollbars rather than expanding the height of the div that contains it.  I can't figure out why this is happening.  I suppressed scrollbars in the control and did my best to configure my css such that the height of the div is dynamic.

Below is an abbreviated version of my asp.net markup showing only those elements that are related to layout.  Can someone please tell me what I need to do to make the height of the multipage div dynamic?

```
<head runat="server">
<style type="text/css">
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body 
{
    height: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
    background-color: #144e77;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: DejaVuSansBook, Sans-Serif;
}
#multipage
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;

}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background:url(AuthImages/bg.jpg) repeat; margin:0px 0px 0px 0px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


<div class="wrapper">
<div id="header_container">
<div id="header" style="width:100%; height:75px;">
<div id="logo" style="float:left"></div>
<div id="welcome" style="float:right; margin-right: 5px; margin-top:5px;"> 
</div>
</div>

</div>
    <div id="tabs" style="width:100%; height:25px; border-bottom: 2px solid #144e77">

    <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" 
        SelectedIndex="0" Width="100%" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1">
        <Tabs>
        <!--tabs are here-->
        </Tabs>
    </telerik:RadTabStrip>

</div>

<div id="multipage">
    <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" ScrollBars="None">
    <!--RadPageViews are here-->    
</div>

<div class="push"></div>

</div>

<div class="footer">
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/O7tPq.png I copied your code and used a RadMultiPage. When the button is clicked, the page is changed and as you see the div itself adjust accordingly to fit the taller control. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what this image is intended to depict.  Is it possible you uploaded the wrong image? The scenario you describe is indeed what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: The image there is hard to see cause you do not get to see the postback that happens when the button is pressed. When the button is pressed the DIV there expands to fit that tall control on the right. Let me see if I can snag the code, thus allowing you to compare it with yours and check the differences.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way via CSS to make a *dynamic* frame height.

I am not familiar with ASP nor RadMultiPage, however one solution is to use a javascript+css based tab navigation system that dynamically adjusts the height of the content container to match that of the height required/created by the content.

There's an informal list of a few [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/50-nice-clean-css-tab-based-navigation-scripts/).

I seem to remember [this one](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/1.1.1/) as being useful.

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and create a fresh Telerik site and copy the code below over the existing **html** to **/html** section.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
    * {
    margin: 0;
    }
    html, body
    {
        height: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
    }
    .footer, .push {
        height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
        background-color: #144e77;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: DejaVuSansBook, Sans-Serif;
    }
    #multipage
    {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        background-color: Gray;
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">


    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>


<div class="wrapper">
<div id="header_container">
<div id="header" style="width:100%; height:75px;">
<div id="logo" style="float:left"></div>
<div id="welcome" style="float:right; margin-right: 5px; margin-top:5px;">
</div>
</div>

</div>
    <div id="tabs" style="width:100%; height:25px; border-bottom: 2px solid #144e77">


</div>

<div id="multipage" style="width: 100%">
    <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" ScrollBars="None" 
        SelectedIndex="0" Width="742px">
    <!--RadPageViews are here-->
        <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server">
            <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>

        </telerik:RadPageView>
        <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView2" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="461px"></asp:TextBox>
        </telerik:RadPageView>
    </telerik:RadMultiPage>   
</div>

<div class="push">
</div>

</div>

<div class="footer">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then add this to the code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadMultiPage1.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Run it and tell me if that works. As I recall I had to close a few tags that you left open in your code.